# too many values to unpack in iterating tuple including tuple

Tags: python, tuples, unpack

```
metro_areas = [
        ('Tokyo', 'JP', 36,933, (35.689722, 139.591593)),
        ('Delhi NCR', 'IN', 21.935, (38.52938, 77.39456)),
        ('Mexico City', 'MX', 30.194, (19.3452, -99.18284)),
        ('New York-Newark', 'US', 20.104, (40.80381, -74.5821)),
        ('Sao Paulo', 'BR', 19.842, (-23,494921, -49.474743))
]

fmt = '{:15} | {:9.4f} | {:9.4f}'
for name, cc, pop, (latitude, longtitude) in metro_areas:
    if longtitude <= 0:
        print(fmt.format(name, latitude, longtitude))
```

running code occurs error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tuple_unpacking.py", line 33, in <module>
    for name, cc, pop, (latitude, longtitude) in metro_areas:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

this is exactly same code as in textbook, but occurs error.

What should I fix in code?

Comment: In the first line, you wrote `36,933` instead of `36.933`

Comment: Also in the last latitude value: `-23,494921` should be `-23.494921`

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the first line of the list,

```
('Tokyo', 'JP', 36,933, (35.689722, 139.591593)),
```

should be,

```
('Tokyo', 'JP', 36.933, (35.689722, 139.591593)),
```

Comment: good catch, but terminology note, in Python, this is a *list* not an array

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's true! I will edit that.